# how to avoid xml caching plain javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to avoid xml caching. I read about this solution: [How to force browser to reload updated XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84243/how-to-force-browser-to-reload-updated-xml-file)
But no example is provided for a newbie! I think this is the part of my code for requesting XML where something has to be changed

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",link_xml,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Can someon provide help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing `xmlhttp.send();` you can use:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(“Cache-Control”, “no-cache”);
```

or

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(“Pragma”, “no-cache”);
```